# Mac OS X screen does not keep current directory

Tags: macos, mac, gnu-screen

I have problem using screen on Mac OS X. When i type `screen` from a certain directory, it always switches to my home directory instead of keeping current.

```
[akhkharu@andrey-macbook ~/ror]$ screen -v
Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06
```

My .screenrc file:

```
shell -$SHELL
termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@
```

Answer (score 2):

This does not happen if you remove your `shell -$SHELL` line from your `.screenrc`. It shouldn't be needed anyway, as screen will run your default shell.